# How to use =+ in Extjs?

Tags: extjs

I am trying to sum all of the time submitted. But I don't think extjs allows the use of =+. Is there any other way I can achieve my goal?

This is what I am trying to show : `console.log(time=+ time);`

Answer (score 1):

ExtJS is "just" JavaScript and there is no magical mapping from `=+` to "sum all of" in JavaScript. Using the presented form is equivalent to `time = (0 + time)` (the result of the expression is `0 + time`), which is hardly useful.

Either create a loop over the "times" (it should be a sequence such as an Array!) and use a "sum" variable; or, better, use one of the JavaScript functions/libraries (including those which are available in ExtJS) that support a `sum` or higher-order [`fold/reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function<sup>1</sup>.

(In fact, [Ext.Array already has a `sum`](http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.Array.html).. how nice is that?)

---

<sup>1</sup> The example on the MDC page for [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) *is* a summation function, presented here with some modifications for clarity:

```
var times = [0,1,2,3,4];
var sum = times.reduce(function(runningSum, number){
  return runningSum + number;
}, 0);
```

If the items of the `times` sequence are not numbers, then this can be used (with the appropriately modified function) as `Ext.Array.sum` requires a sequence of numbers.

If older browsers must be targeted (such as IE 8 or before), use [es5-shim.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) and move on to more productive things.